# How to force client request to webservice to use HTTP/1.1?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Our coporate security has blocked the use of HTTP/1.0. I have a SOAP webservice and a java client program to invoke the webservice. Here is the code below.

- args[0] - is the end point URL
- args[1] - is the XML input converted to a string.

By default request is going in as HTTP/1.0:

```
public class ClientWS
{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try
        {
            if (args == null || args.length == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Nothing passed in...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            String endpointURL = args[0]; 

            FileInputStream f=new FileInputStream(args[1]);
            int len=f.available();

            String ipmXML = "";

            for(int i=1;i<=len;i++)
            {
            ipmXML=ipmXML+(char)f.read();
            }


            //System.out.println("endpointURL........."+endpointURL);
            //System.out.println("imp xml    ........."+ipmXML);

            Service service = new Service();
            Call call = (Call) service.createCall();

            call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new java.net.URL(endpointURL) );
            call.setOperationName( new QName("", "executeProgram") );

            System.out.println("invoking service.........");
            String ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] { ipmXML } );
            System.out.println("String Returned : \n" + ret);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error===="+e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```